# How to make DateTimePicker work on iOS and Android?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have taken a look at different DateTimePicker implementations to use in my application. I decided to use [this one](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). So it works perfect with Firefox, but I can't get it to work on iOS and Android.

Or is there a trick how to activate the native DateTimePickers on iOS and Android?

My implementation of the component:

```
<!-- Bootstrap + jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/simplex/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

<!-- Some custom CSS -->

<!-- DateTimePicker -->
<script src="http://localhost/packages/moment/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/packages/datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/packages/datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried on iOS 8 and it works, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: I added some code. I checked again, it does not work. I opend Firefox and looked at the sourcecode. My DTPicker is outside my head-tags. But that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: I should clarify, I tried the above referenced author's github page on iOS 8 for the datetimepicker as your question led to question its functionality.

Comment: I would also question your references to your js/css files.  When testing on Android and iOS, do these devices have line of sight to your "localhost" address.  The behavior of "not activated" seems to lend towards not all resources being loaded.

Comment: Interessting. I access the page (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and the neither the native iOS nor any DateTimePicker shows up. iPhone 4S with iOS 8.1.2

Comment: Yes, thats sounds logic. I'm such a idiot :D Because my typeahead isn't working on mobile, too. And Bootstrap works because I use a CDN. I will try that!

Comment: @blink-fish Yes that was my issue >.< Thank you very much! Can you write this as an answer? I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your references to your js/css files. When testing on Android and iOS, do these devices have line of sight to your "localhost" address. The behavior of "not activated" seems to lend towards not all resources being loaded.